# Trigger alarm after every 2 days

Tags: android

I want to set alarm which do not trigger on installation but triggers after every 2 days with defined time also. so far i am using below code which uses only time on which alarm triggers and after that repeatedly triggers after every 2 minutes. Any idea?

```
AlarmManager am = this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setrepeating(
    AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    calender.getTimeInMillis(),
    1000 * 60 * 2,
    pendingIntent
);
```

Answer (score 0):

With `1000 * 60 * 2` you have told it to trigger every two minutes.
To make it trigger every two days try with `1000 * 60 * 60 * 48`

Edit:
Time is represented as amount of milliseconds making it:

```
1000                 -> 1 second  
1000 * 60            -> 1 minute  
1000 * 60 * 60       -> 1 hour  
1000 * 60 * 60 * 24  -> 1 day
```

Comment: thanks alot mate. i will try this, seems i have found my solution. any tip for not triggering alarm on installation?

Comment: The second argument specifies the first time of triggering an alarm.  Currently it is `calender.getTimeInMillis()` meaning that it will trigger at that exact moment. To postpone it add the amount of time after "now". If it is two days after scheduling an alarm try with `calender.getTimeInMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2`